# Remove port aliases in iptables

Tags: centos, iptables

How can I make iptables show me port numbers instead of aliases for well known port numbers (eg. http for 80, https for 443 etc.). Is there a way to make it show just port numbers at all times?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `-n` option.

```
$ iptables --help
[...]
  --numeric     -n              numeric output of addresses and ports
```

Comment: What about the CentOS/Linux Setup Utility - I use that configure the firewall most of the time - any way to disable the aliases in there?

Comment: It works in CentOS too. To list the rules, try: iptables -L -n